# problemas al traer data de una REST API

Tags: api, rest

Debo realizar una aplicación en Angular a partir de data traida de una REST API:

El detalle es que a pesar de tener las credenciales y el token, por más que intento solo obtengo mensajes de Unauthorized y 401.

Puede alguien por favor decirme por qué ocurre esto?

Estos son los datos para conectarse a la API:

API: URL: https://dev.tuten.cl/TutenREST/rest/user/contacto%40tuten.cl/bookings?current=true
adminemail: testapis@tuten.cl
email: contacto@tuten.cl
current: true
app: APP_BCK
token: 15uegum7jub2n9pfl7aoco9gdo

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que esa es la forma correcta de realizar la petición? Porque en la página del [sitio](https://dev.tuten.cl/TutenREST/#!/user/bookings) indica otra cosa. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Según las notas de ese endpoint (`/user/{email}/bookings`), solamente **administradores** tienen acceso a ese recurso. Y por lo que veo, el código de estado HTTP de tu solicitud es 401 (No autorizado), pues significa que el usuario con que hiciste el request no es administrador.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.